# Loading and correctly displaying an image dataset using pytorch Dataloader

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch

I'm trying to load a custom dataset for training a neural network, but before I load them in, I would like to verify that they've been loaded correctly. So far it looks like they are not being loaded correctly, but I can't figure out what gives the images the format that they get.

This is the code that I'm loading the images with, and then displaying them.

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(20,20))

def load_dataset():
    data_path = 'processedData/HE/train/'
    train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(
        root=data_path,
        transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()
    )
    train_loader = DataLoader(
        train_dataset, batch_size=64
    )
    return train_loader
x_train = load_dataset()

datathing = next(iter(x_train))

for i, ax in enumerate(axarr.flat):
    ax.imshow(datathing[0][i].view(128,128,3))
    ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

When running this with the images, the output [looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INF0S.png)

It is suppose to look something [like these images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTAQ4.png)

I have been trying with different image datasets, but all the sets return the same format, so my question is:

- How to load images and then displaying them in their real format using pytorch's dataloader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.view(128, 128, 3)` is messing up with the images.

As you can read in the documentation of the transformation [`.ToTensor(...)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToTensor):

> [...]
>
> Converts a PIL Image or numpy.ndarray **(H x W x C)** in the range [0, 255] to a torch.FloatTensor of shape **(C x H x W)** in the range [0.0, 1.0]
>
> [...]

That is, the channel dimension is moved from the last to the first dimension. You can see that in the [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/681c6c1115035a9dfd2f05ede1a00620532e2f01/torchvision/transforms/functional.py#L43-L102):

```py
# ...
img = torch.from_numpy(pic.transpose((2, 0, 1)))
# ...
```

Therefore, you cannot simply call `.view(...)`; you have to transpose it back. In PyTorch, you can use the `.permute(...)` function for that. Something like this:

```py
ax.imshow(datathing[0][i].permute(1, 2, 0))
```